# Sum up similar values in VLOOKUP/INDEX-MATCH excel functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have an issue with a vlookup/index-match formula in excel 2010.

I have a table that contains duplicate values in the name column.
I have a table in another sheet that reference the name & amount from the first sheet.
in case a duplicate name exist in the original table, it should sum the amount.

For example, look at the pic below.
ABC is a duplicate name, and it's amount should be zero.
How can I use Vlookup/index-match formulas in order to display "0" in the result when I lookup the name ABC?

In the destination sheet, the name only appears once, hence I don't want to add another ABC to the dest table.

[image: Example of the problem]
Thanks !
Roni.

Comment: I'd suggest using Pivot tables

Comment: The originated table IS a PIVOT table. 
I didn't add the whole column.
Because there's another SECTOR column, the ABC value exist in two sectors.

Comment: But if it already is a pivot table, why not simply add another one (ie copy this one) and take out the sector column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` and or `INDEX`/`MATCH` will only return you one entry (the first match) - so you cannot use it for summing (unless in an array formula).

However, using `SUMIFS` (or in Excel 2003 and earlier `SUMIF`) will be just what you need: So In F2, you could write:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,E2)
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like the right answer, I'll check it out when I'll get back to that customer on Friday.