# Return a value from a specific cell address if condition of another cell is met

Tags: excel, numbers, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Based on the the table in the image below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gOTluJq.png]

I want to return a value from column G if the value in column A with the same row is equal to a value I specify.

For example, in the case of the linked image, Return `6120` from column G if the value in column A is `Squat`.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a vlookup. It's a common spreadsheet problem.

Have a look at this answer on stack overflow: [Using VLOOKUP()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808932/using-vlookup)
and this http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html

These are for excel but basically all spreadsheets will handle this similarly. 
Next time, just include the image directly in your question. Makes for better reading.

Comment: sorry for the image issue, I need 10 points on here in order to embed it unfortunately. But thank you for the solution. If I had multiple instances of what I'm searching for ("Squats"), is there a way to add up all values it would return?

Comment: The thing with spreadsheets is that if you want to layer information like that, you can either create multiple rows or dive into "Fun with formulas" Here's a SO answer that explains what you're looking for in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815705/sum-up-similar-values-in-vlookup-index-match-excel-functions and a third-party site: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/05/excel-vlookup-sum-sumif/

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a common enough request that a function has been dedicated to it, namely `VLOOKUP`.

VLOOKUP has the following four parameters:
1. what you are looking for: presumably this is where you'll reference a cell that has the text you happen to be looking for "SQUAT" etc...
2. the table of values that contain all of the things you want to search across: in your instance this would probably encompass columns A-H and rows 3-8 (exclude headings)
3. the number of columns from the right to look: in your instance this would be 7
4. a true/false value indicating whether you want exact or fuzzy matching: you probably want exact

Comment: thank you for the solution. If I had multiple instances of what I'm searching for ("Squats"), is there a way to add up all values it would return?

Comment: Then you would need to use pivotTables OR the SUMIF formula - looks like I got beaten to the answer by under a minute!

Comment: a SUMIFS formula ended up working perfectly for what I was trying to do. Thank you for the clarification on VLOOKUP, though!